# JS: Click on a single letter to move it

Tags: javascript

I need to click on a single letter in the word. When a letter is clicked, it needs to move to its new spot (the first empty location of a new word). The user needs to guess the word from shuffled letters. How can I do that?
I have this simple javascript code that gives me a random shuffled word from array, what should i do next?

```
function GetValue()
{
var myarray,random,mix,p1,p2,sa;
myarray= new Array("dog","cat","rabbit","horse");
random = myarray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myarray.length)];
mix=random.split("");
for(var i=0;i<10;i++) {
p1=Math.floor(Math.random()*mix.length);
p2=Math.floor(Math.random()*mix.length);
sa=mix[p1]
segi[p1]=mix[p2];
mix[p2]=sa;
}
mix=mix.join("")
document.getElementById("word").innerHTML=mix;
}
```

Comment: There are probably a lot of ways to do this, why don't you imagine one and then begin to try and implement it. If you have problems with your implementation or the solution you imagined, then the community might be able to help you with that. Stack Overflow is not a place to ask people to do your work for you.

Answer (score 0):

rather than just placing the raw word in the dom, you should separate each letter into a span element. That way you can attach a click handler to each of the letters.

```
<span class="letter">d</span><span class="letter">o</span><span class="letter">g</span>
```

You also need to insert the blank "placeholder" to swap with the clicked letter

```
<span class="letter">d</span><span class="letter">o</span><span class="letter">g</span><span class="blank">&nbsp</span>
```

This would all be much more easily handled in jQuery